# Why javascript expression '[[][[]]+[]][+[]][++[+[]][+[]]]' result is 'n'?

Tags: javascript, operators, expression

I know first execute `+[]`, and convert it to `0`

so the expression become

```
[[][[]]+[]][0][++[0][0]]
```

then I think the `++` have high priority, but the `++[0]` seem is illegal

So why the final result is `n` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavlovian response, I just had to work it out. :-)

Start from the inside out:

```
[    [][[]]+[]    ][0][    ++[0][0]    ]
```

Let's take `[][[]]+[]` first: `[]` is an empty array. The `[[]]` after it is a property accessor. So the inner `[]` there is coerced to the string `""`. `[][""]` is `undefined` (there is no property on the array with the name `""`.) Taking `undefined + []` coerces both sides to string and gives us `"undefined"`. So now we have:

```
[    "undefined"    ][0][    ++[0][0]    ]
```

The next part is fairly obvious: `["undefined"][0]` is `"undefined`". So now we have:

```
"undefined"[    ++[0][0]    ]
```

Let's do that property accessor, `++[0][0]`: `[0]` is an array containing 0. `[0]` after it indexes into it, so we're incrementing the array entry at index 0 (which is 0) to make it 1.

So now we have:

```
"undefined"[1]
```

...which is "n".