# Javascript confusion with types and results of adding empty arrays and objects

Tags: javascript

I have came across this comparisons:

```
[] + []   === ''; // true
[] * 1    === 0;  // true
false + 1 === 1;  // true
```

The last comparison makes sense, but what I am wondering is and can't find a resource about why `[] + []` equals empty string and why `[] * 1` equals `0`?

Comment: For [] + [], see this explanation http://2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

Comment: you can't do mathematics with an array so javascript convert the `[]` to `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the) linked from the comment posted by hardik-shah would certainly give you a better understanding of how these type of evaluations get handled in javascript. That answer points to the ecma docs, which is also useful. I'll try and give a limited explanation of how the examples you posted work.

Below I've quoted the article I used as the basis to interpreting how these instances of the `+` operator work. I believe I've interpreted the article correctly, but I'm no expert on these things so I would be happy to be corrected.

---

```
[] + []   === ''; // true
```

This is true because both operands are objects; `[].valueOf` doesn't return a primitive, so `[].toString` is used, which evaluates to `''`

---

```
[] * 1    === 0;  // true
```

This is true because, as one of the operands is a primitive, arithmetic is used rather than concatenation. `'' * 1` evaluates to `0 * 1`, which  equals `0`

---

```
false + 1 === 1;  // true
```

Both operands here are primitives, so arithmetic will be used. `Number(false)` gives us 0, so `0 + 1` equals `1`

---

From [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/)

> 1. If at least one operand is an object, it is converted to a primitive value (string, number or boolean)
> 2. After conversion, if at least one operand is string type, the second operand is converted to string and the concatenation is executed
> 3. In other case both operands are converted to numbers and arithmetic addition is executed.
>
> The object to primitive conversion:
>
> - If object type is Date, then toString() method is used;
> - In other case
>     valueOf() method is used, if it returns a primitive value;
> - In other case (if valueOf() doesn't exist or doesn't return a primitive value),
>     then toString() method is used. This happens most of the times.