# Implicit type coercion with objects

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion, type-coercion

```
var a = {};
a + 1 // return "[object Object]1"
```

I know why this happened. Object toPrimitive happened and after a.toString return [object Object] and merge with number
But why when I type code like this

```
{} + 1 // return 1
```

Object not converted string?

Also why object toPrimitive hint Number return 0
When object convert to number this is look valueOf function and why valueOf return 0?

Comment: [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one is an object and you're adding object with number

```
var a = {};
a + 1 // return "[object Object]1"
```

Where as second one is just [`block statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#Block_Statement) not object

```
{} + 1 // return 1
```

Answer (score 3):

When *not* in an expression context, `{}` will be interpreted as an empty block, so

```
{} + 1
```

is like

```
{
  // no statements here
}
+1
```

where the `+` is the unary plus operator. The `{}` here does not denote an object literal, but a block, and the `+1` is the final (and only) expression evaluated, so that's what the console will display if you're just typing into the console.

If you *are* in an expression context, `{} + 1` will indeed evaluate to `[object Object]1`:

```js
console.log(
  {} + 1
);
```