# Why is {} || 3 a syntax error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This reminds me of [Gary Bernhardt's "Wat" talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat), but why is `{} || 3` a syntax error?

```
> 3 || {}
3
> {} || 3
VM2330:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||'
> {} + 3
3
> a = {}
{}
> a || 3
{}
```

Comment: [Block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) vs Object

Comment: `{}` is interpreted as a code block. So you evaluate (essentially) `|| 3`

Comment: I'm assuming `{}` is interpreted as a block. Try `({} || 3)`.

Comment: Also, related to Wat - this is essentially [the same behaviour that was demonstrated there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the). Check 3. and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an expression with patentheses.

```
({} || 3)
```

Oterwise you take a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and this is not an expression for use with an operator.

Comment: You can also just wrap the object in parentheses to let the interpreter know this is an object instance rather than an execution context. `({}) || 3`