# Why does !{}.length evaluate to true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why does `!{}.length` evaluate to `true` in JavaScript if `{}.length` throws the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`. In fact, `!{}.definitelyNotAMethod` also evaluates to `true`.

Objects don't possess length methods, but if you were expecting the object to be an array and didn't perform the proper validations, this could cause a hard-to-spot bug in your code base.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Comment: @epascarello nice find! Didn't see that post

Comment: Should be `!{}` is false and it will be `false.toString().length`. Now other one `{}` is seen as a block (not object)

Comment: It's just the empty object literal syntax is treated as [a block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) when you do `{}.length`.If you do `const a = {}; a.length` doesn't throw any error. So, you don't have to worry about this throwing an error during validtion.