# What is the difference between ({} + '') and {} + ''?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `({} + "")` and `{} + ""` ?

```js
Case 1: 
({} + "") \\ "[object Object]"
{} + "" \\ 0

Case 2:
({ a: 1 } + '') \\ "[object Object]"
{ a: 1 } + '' \\ 0

Case 3:
const obj = {};
(obj + '') \\ "[object Object]"
obj + '' \\ "[object Object]"
```

JavaScript is an amazing language!!!

Comment: One of them is interpreted empty code block with `+""` and the other one is an empty object literal + "". [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856)

Comment: What?  `{ a: 1 }`  is also an empty code block?  @adiga

Comment: It is interpreted as a code block with a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). If you try to add another property like `{ a: 1, b: 2 } + ''`, you should get an error because it's an invalid labeled statement:

Comment: Please check the duplicates at the top of the page for detailed explanations