Why does Chrome DevTools throw when comparing {}?
The comparison {} === {} throws in Chrome DevTools, whereas it runs fine in Node for example.
Any idea why?


Because braces can denote objects or blocks.

Try ({} === {})

It's funny that chrome throw wherease Node doesn't.

The strange thing is that you can write {} + {}. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9033306/1491895 explains why this works.

Interesting ... I only wonder why node.js treats the first {} as an object. Node.js seems to look ahead and treats the {} differently if there is a comparison operator involved. E.g. compare { "" } vs. { "" } === {}; 1st is treated as block and valid, 2nd is treated as object and causes a syntax error inside the object (i'd expect an error at the ===). Node.js even displays ({ "" } < {}) in the error message, note the round brackets.

It is the way how it is compiled. If you combine it with () it can work. Such scenarios exist in node as well, where the compile can not now you want to construct an object. In this example byside the example above ({}) === ({}) should work as well.
