# {}+{}="[object Object]", but {}+[]=0?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome console (v. 55.0.2883):

```
{} + {}
"[object Object][object Object]"
```

but

```
{} + [] 
0

{} + {} == "[object Object][object Object]"
false
```

Why in first case chrome takes first braces as an object instead of empty block? Some new es6 feature?

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the). In my case the behavior is different

Comment: Why? Because JavaScript.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that discussion ({}+{}==NaN). In first case the behavior is different

Comment: Chrome is probably [dumping some other values](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#0-4). Try `x={}+[]`

Comment: Who cares, really?

Comment: *"Some new es6 feature?"* No. It's a Chrome specific thing. Depending on your input it tries to determine whether you meant to write an expression or statements. The console (input and output) is not standardized. E.g. `{;}+{}` returns `NaN` (not a syntax error).

Comment: See also: [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Comment: @dabadaba No. Because Chrome, which does some dark magic under the hood to confuse people.

Comment: @FelixKling—also in Safari and Opera. It's answered in the dup I linked in a comment by  hugomg and linking to [*What is \[\] + \[\] in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021109/what-is-in-javascript/9021351#9021351). I've reopened the question, but I still think it's a duplicate. @Oriol—I think it's two legitimate ways to interpret the same bit of code.